# JPA/Hibernate inheritance without id

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, inheritance

Is it possible to make inheritance in JPA/Hibernate without id? 
My use case:

I have multiple entities and I want every time change is being done, timestamp being recorded. So I created AbstractResource and want each derived class inherit properties and logic (to avoid writing same stuff over and over again in each class).

My problem that hibernate wants an ID to entity, and I do not care about id, since my only concern is additional properties. And each entity can have whatever id it wants (String, int, long, different name, etc.).

I tried with Embeddable, but looks like hibernate does not support inheritance for Embeddable. Do you have any ideas, how my task can be achieved?

My parent class from which "Audited" entities are derived:

```
@Embeddable
@EntityListeners(AbstractResourceListener.class)
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public class AbstractResource {
    private long modifyTimestamp;

    @Column(name = "_MODIFY_TIMESTAMP", nullable = true)
    public long getModifyTimestamp() {
    return modifyTimestamp;
    }

    public void setModifyTimestamp(long modifyTimestamp) {
    this.modifyTimestamp = modifyTimestamp;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@MappedSuperclass is an annotation for super classes that you can extend and use in audit. Please see [example](https://github.com/danjee/hibernate-mappings)